# Huawei's Safe not found, how to recover the files?

Tags: data-recovery, huawei

I have Huawei Y5 (2019) running on Android 9 Pie, and I'm using its built-in Safe to secure my photos.

[image: Huawei's built-in Safe]

I made a Safe, put some photos in it, and made a password and it was working good.

Now, when I try to open it, I get this message and I can't find my photos.

[image]

> **Note**
>
> AMN-LX9 not found. Choose another Safe?

How to recover the photos?